# Killing CPU bound child process

Tags: node.js

I have a child process spawned using child_process.fork and would like to terminate it. The problem is that the child process does some lengthy CPU bound calculation and I don't have control over it. That is, the CPU bound code fragment cannot be restructured to make use of process.nextTick or polling.

A very simplified example:

parent.js

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork('child.js');
```

child.js

```
...
while(true){} // lengthy computation which I cannot modify
...
```

Is it possible to terminate it? Preferably in a way that allows catching the exit event in the child in order to do some cleanups?

Sending SIGTERM/SIGKILL/etc using child.kill() doesn't
seem to work on Windows. I assume even if it works on other OSes it wouldn't kill the process anyway due to child not being able to process events while doing the computation.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this the messy way by [using the PID](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_pid) of the process and killing it at the OS level.

Not sure how to do it in windows, but in Linux/mac I've done:

```
var cp      = require('child_process'),
    badJob  = cp.fork('badFile.js');

cp.execSync('kill -9 ' + badJob.pid);
```

[The signal 9 is caught at the Kernel level](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0080.php), so the condition of the process is irrelevant.

**Edit:** In Windows you can use [taskkill](http://www.computerhope.com/taskkill.htm) instead of kill. ex:

```
cp.execSync('taskkill /f ' + badJob.pid);
```